# How can I configure HAProxy to use all servers in a backend if none are UP

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I'm running HAProxy as a TCP loadbalancer in front of an on-prem Kubernetes cluster. I have set up a small app on each cluster node which return HTTP200 when the node is considered healthy. One of the healthchecks it performs is to query the KubeAPI and verify the status according to K8S itself. Now, if for some reason the Kube API goes down, all nodes will be considered unhealthy at the same time, even though the applications running on the workers are still available.

I'd like to set up HAProxy in such a way that whenever all worker nodes are down according to the health check, HAProxy just assumes they are all alive. If indeed all nodes are down, whether or not traffic is forwarded doesn't matter. If the reason they're all down is that some shared component doesn't respond, just blindly sending traffic will at least keep the service going.

I've parsed the [HAProxy reference](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/2-2r1/onepage/) in search of an option which does this. I can't seem to find one. I think I should be able to get this functionality by registering each worker node twice, once regularly and once with the `backup` option specified. Then adding `allbackups` to the backend would make it so that if all worker nodes are down, alls worker nodes are used as a backup. That would look like this:

```
backend workers 
  mode tcp
  option httpchk HEAD /
  option allbackups
  server worker-001-1 <address-1> check port 32000
  server worker-001-2 <address-2> check port 32000
  server worker-001-1-backup <address-1> backup
  server worker-001-2-backup <address-2> backup
```

While this solution seems to work. It seems very hacky. Is there any way to do this in a cleaner way. Is there an option I missed in the reference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a more suitable solution in this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/923624/255500

It boils down to using backend switching rules and creating two backends for each group of clusters:

```
frontend ingress
  bind *:80 http
  bind *:443 https
  bind *:30000-32676 nodeports
  mode tcp
  default_backend workers
  use_backend workers_backup if { nbsrv(workers) eq 0 }

backend workers 
  mode tcp
  option httpchk HEAD /
  server worker-001-1 <address-1> check port 32000
  server worker-001-2 <address-2> check port 32000

backend workers_backup
  mode tcp
  server worker-001-1 <address-1> no-check
  server worker-001-2 <address-2> no-check
```

Once backend `workers` has zero servers up, backend `workers_backup` will be used. It's still registering each node twice, but I think this is the better solution.

Comment: Can I setup multiple cluster node in one cloud server(256GB RAM, 1Gbps bandwidth)? or should I purchase more servers to install multiple node? so one node is one host?

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible that you're trying to solve the wrong problem? If the nodes report as unhealthy if the Kube API is unavailable, then should you focus on making Kube API highly available?

In this article, they describe a way to create a highly available control plane. https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/

Comment: Kube API is already highly available, but that doesn't mean it never goes down. Same with etcd. If etcd for some reason goes down, the API can't fetch the node status and traffic gets cut off, even though the applications that need to handle the traffic are up, running, and reachable.

Comment: Do you mean that you run multiple master nodes? The solution you are proposing seems like it's going in the wrong direction.

Comment: Alternatively, just disable health checks in HAProxy.